# How do I find who sent the transaction

Tags: transactions, blockchain, address

[image]

The address: 1A5PsNLUs6BNWvNSzooGSFVKdkaJ4e2TG2
TXID: 
Amount: 0.0127

Comment: the bitcoin system is a pseudonymous system, where spending of funds is intentionally not linked to names or owners. With the idea of not re-using addresses, it makes it nearly impossible, to relate any spends to a particular person.

Comment: Is it possible to find which address sent the transaction? In the ethereum blockchain, it is possible to find the sender and the receiver.

Answer (score 0):

I drop my comment in the answer section, cause there is not enough space...
looking at the [raw transaction](https://blockchain.info/rawtx/497e90946be5ac4076497476c221d5165549e45040700d06f0b10091e2f144d5), one can see many funds from several addresses mixed to other outputs. The closest I can get, is that tx_out[2] is corresponding to the mentioned address. So there is not a single source, from which the funds were sent.

All the inputs are 2-of-3 (multisig) addresses, and none of the included keys of these 2-of-3 corresponds to the mentioned address. As such I cannot say, where the funds came from. Essentially this transaction was compiled to collect funds from 10 transactions, and redistribute them  over 11 output addresses.

As the amounts are fairly similar, I guess it is a payout schema like used in faucets. Also exchanges use this style of "funds moving" between hot and cold wallets.